# Probability theory

Tags: probability

Let S = {a, b, c} be a sample space. For any outcome x is an element of S, let m(x) denote the likelihood of that outcome.

Let m(a) = 1/6
m(b) = 1/2
m(c) 1/3

Find the probability of all 8 subsets of S.

So, all 8 subsets would be ({}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {ab}, {ac}, {bc}, {abc}) and I would get the answer by multiplying the probabilities.

So, m(ab) = 1/6 * 1/2 = 1/12.

Is this the correct way to approach this problem? I guess I am confused by the definition of sample space. Shouldn't the only outcomes of the experiment be a, b or c if that is all that is in the sample space?

Answer (score 0):

The elements of the [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) and [events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_%28probability_theory%29) are generally different things. An event is a subset of the sample space that may contain several elements of the sample space. If we can assign probabilities to the elements of the sample space, this will give us the probabilities of the events. In the example on Wikipedia, there is a probability that you pull a face card (12 out of 52) and a probability of pulling a spade (1 out of 4). The probability of pulling a card that is a face card and a spade is 3 out of 52.